# How to render the Mvc Mobile View in a iPhone?

Tags: model-view-controller, mobile, view

I got to a stage that my Mvc mobile view (iPhone) is rendering in a web browser.

Eg.

- Home

  - Mobile

    - iPhone

      - Index.aspx

My question is how can I get this View into an iPhone type simulator? I don't know hot to get the mobile view to a nice looking simulator. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I can use this to show the web mobile content. Doesn't work in most browsers but work in this device.
http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662